# Is it possible to get the list of moves out of the levenshtein function?

Tags: php

I need to compare the similarity of words, I have a sample entered by the user and control from the administrator. The levenshtein function does this just right, as in how the difference / control length translates to a percentage in my situation. However, I'd also like to highlight the mistakes users made but afaik, the levenshtein function built into php can't give me any information for that.

OK I figured "I'll make my own levenshtein function and make it spit out the locations where it does the changes".. but before I even got to any of that, I made a simpler version

```
function toMbChars($s) {
    $len = mb_strlen($s); 
    $ret = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        array_push($ret, mb_substr($s, $i, 1));
    }
    return $ret;
}

function cmpLevenshteinDistanceOpt($a, $aLen, $b, $bLen) {
    if (!$aLen) return $bLen;
    if (!$bLen) return $aLen;

    $cost = $a[$aLen - 1] != $b[$bLen - 1];

    return min( cmpLevenshteinDistanceOpt($a, $aLen - 1, $b, $bLen    ) + 1,
                cmpLevenshteinDistanceOpt($a, $aLen    , $b, $bLen - 1) + 1,
                cmpLevenshteinDistanceOpt($a, $aLen - 1, $b, $bLen - 1) + $cost );      
}
function cmpLevenshteinDistance($a, $b) {
    $aChars = toMbChars($a);
    $bChars = toMbChars($b);
    return cmpLevenshteinDistanceOpt($aChars, count($aChars), $bChars, count($bChars));
}
```

And it fails hard on the performance, it takes like 13 seconds to compute the distance between 10 letter words while the built in function does it in a few milliseconds.

So now I'm looking at 2 questions:

1. Is there any way to make the built in function tell me where and what kinds of "costs" it added up for the minimal distance?
2. Is there any way to optimize my function to perform as well as the built in version?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Levenshtein function, however the docs  http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php have an example where they store the closest match, could you not do something similar and then just compare those 2 words manually yourself? I've added a crude compare function at the end here, but you might want to tweak it for errors etc. and it's currently only built for if the user entered word is longer than the control, but hopefully it's a starting point

```
<?php
// input misspelled word
$input = 'caarrrot';

// array of words to check against
$words  = array('apple','pineapple','banana','orange',
                'radish','carrot','pea','bean','potato');

// no shortest distance found, yet
$shortest = -1;

// loop through words to find the closest
foreach ($words as $word) {

    // calculate the distance between the input word,
    // and the current word
    $lev = levenshtein($input, $word);

    // check for an exact match
    if ($lev == 0) {

        // closest word is this one (exact match)
        $closest = $word;
        $shortest = 0;

        // break out of the loop; we've found an exact match
        break;
    }

    // if this distance is less than the next found shortest
    // distance, OR if a next shortest word has not yet been found
    if ($lev <= $shortest || $shortest < 0) {
        // set the closest match, and shortest distance
        $closest  = $word;
        $shortest = $lev;
    }
}

echo "Input word: $input\n";
if ($shortest == 0) {
    echo "Exact match found: $closest\n";
} else {

    echo "Did you mean: $closest?\n";
    $diff = wordDifference($input, $closest);
    echo $diff;
}

function wordDifference($word1, $word2){
    $difference = '';
    $offset = 0;
    for($i =0; $i < strlen($word1); $i++ ){
        $word1letter = $word1[$i];

        $word2letter = $word2[$i - $offset] ? $word2[$i - $offset] : '';

        if($word1letter !== $word2letter){
            $offset++;
            $difference .= '<span style="background:red">'.$word1letter.'</span>';
        }else{
            $difference .= $word1letter;
        }
    }
    return $difference;
}


?>*
```

Comment: the levenshtein function calculates the minimum amount of changes required for string A to match string B. It does so by considering adding/removing/replacing each letter, brute force style. Each of those changes has a position, that's what I'm looking for. So for instance if the sample is "caaarot" and control is "carrot" then that is 1 delete @ 2 + 1 replace @ 3

Comment: Thanks, I worked out what it does, it was more that I was not overly familiar with it I suppose. Is my example with the added wordDifference function not able to provide what you need? Where I am highlighting the difference in red, you could merely store the index of the letter ($i) and return that to do as you want. You just need to add a check for if the users word is missing a char that the control has

Comment: Its much more complicated than that. If a letter is not in the expected position and it continues through the string to find it, what if it lands on the same but unrelated letter? Then it would just skip a bunch of potentially good letters and be completely out of position. If it doesn't skip, it would need to consider every possible variation of insert/replace/remove which is what the levenshtein algorithm does. Try peneappli as input for instance, it would invalidate almost the entire word while only 2 characters are wrong.